# Compiling a simple MFC project

Tags: c++, mfc, mingw32

I need the DLL that contains the MFC libraries, so I can compile a MFC project with MinWG.

I cannot download Visual C++ because I have a 50mb download limit.

According to Wikipedia, the latest MFC version is MFC 10.0.40219.1, and it is contained in a file called `mfc100.dll`.

Where can I download this file, or the basic MFC framework in general?

Comment: A DLL is useless, you need the .h and .lib files to compile an MFC app.  You'll need to purchase a license, MFC is not included in a the Express edition.  Contact a reseller to obtain a DVD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distribution of MFC*.dll requires a Visual Studio (Professional) license. Hence, you won't find it as a redistributable.

Answer (score 0):

you can find it in Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package ( about 5mb download from Microsoft website)

Comment: It's not in that program. I installed in and extracted the files, and checked both.